# Can I buy an aluminum seatpost with a chromoly frame

Tags: parts, compatibility

I'm starting to plan to build a bike and am looking at parts. I found a frame I like ([Poloandbike CMNDR frameset](https://www.citygrounds.com/collections/bike-frames-framesets/products/poloandbike-cmndr-track-frameset-2017?variant=33581101964)) which is chromoly, but am now trying to find a seatpost to go on it. I believe the seatpost on the frame is 31.6 mm. I found a seatpost I like ([Kalloy Laprade SP243](https://www.citygrounds.com/collections/bike-seat-posts/products/kalloy-laprade-sp243-seatpost?variant=21432091078)) which is made of Al6061T6. My question is, is it alright to have an aluminum seatpost on a chromoly frame? I know some alloys will need grease or different conditions, so I wasn't sure if this would be an alright things to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know of any reason not to.  Pretty sure I have done it for years.

Comment: Yes, but do make sure the size is right though. Looking at the official page, that doesn't seem to be the case: https://poloandbike.com/track/geometries/ The seat tube diameter reported there is 26.4

Comment: Interesting, I saw on another page on their site it was different. I'll contact them about the discrepancy.

Comment: Note that building up a bike from scratch can be more expensive than buying the complete bike and swapping out parts you don't like on it (and possibly selling these parts).

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that and think it will be a nice project to build it all on my own

Comment: You'll probably need to use the shop for a few things though (chasing/facing, installing headset, bottom bracket).

Comment: What would I need to use the shop for? Tools?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark - I stated several tasks which you might want a shop. For example, very few people own bearing presses for headsets/bottom brackets or can chase/face a frame adequately at home. Once you have those, the bike can usually come together with some bicycle housing+wire cutters, a crescent wrench, a socket wrench, some grease and a set of hex keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a problem with putting an aluminum seatpost in a steel frame. It's a pretty common thing to do.

**Make sure to grease the seatpost before putting it in**, lest it get stuck. If it does get stuck, you could try ammonia or drano (sodium hydroxide) or chilling the thing (e.g. with a CO2 cartridge to unstick it). See [this page](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/stuck-seatposts.html) for other stuck seatpost suggestions.

Also, make sure you have the right diameter seatpost. This can be done by checking the documentation for the frame, or using a seatpost measuring tool (which most bike shops should have), or a pair of vernier calipers.